# Tensorflow: Dequeue and then enqueue

Tags: tensorflow

I have a queue (called `queue_A`) and populate 100 elements inside. If I would like to do the following 2 things:

1. Dequeue 1 element from `queue_A`, do some processing on it and enqueue the result into another queue (`queue_B`). The enqueuing op is called `op_B`.
2. Enqueue this element (before processing) back to `queue_A`, and this enqueuing op is called `op_A`.

For achieving 1, I can write:

```
anElement = queue_A.dequeue()
result = proc(anElement)
op_B = queue_B.enqueue(result)
queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_B,
                                    [op_B] * 4)
```

For achieving 2, I can write:

```
anElement = queue_A.dequeue()
op_A = queue_A.enqueue(anElement)
queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_A,
                                    [op_A] * 4)
```

However, I don't know how can I do these two things at once.
Now, I use the following code:

```
anElement = queue_A.dequeue()
op_A = queue_A.enqueue(anElement)
result = proc(anElement)
op_B = queue_B.enqueue(result)
queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_B,
                                    [op_A, op_B] * 4)
```

I expect the size of `queue_A` is a constant, but when I use `session.run(queue_A.size())` to check it, the size is gradually decreasing.
What is wrong with that code? And how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your example has two types of "queue runner":

1. One that runs `op_A`: it dequeues an element from `queue_A`, and enqueues it back to `queue_B`.
2. Another that runs `op_B`: it dequeues an element from `queue_A`, processes it via `proc()`, and enqueues the result back to `queue_B`.

The problem is that, when `op_A` and `op_B` run separately (e.g. in different queue runners, or in different calls to `sess.run()`), they will dequeue *distinct* elements from `queue_A`. The elements dequeued by running `op_B` will never be re-enqueued to `queue_A`, which explains why its size gradually decreases.

To solve this problem, as [Andrei suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39098654/3574081), you need to create an op that runs a single TensorFlow subgraph that performs both `op_A` and `op_B`. The following example should work:

```
anElement = queue_A.dequeue()
op_A = queue_A.enqueue(anElement)
result = proc(anElement)
op_B = queue_B.enqueue(result)

# Creates a single op that enqueues the original element back to queue_A and the 
# processed element to queue_B.
op = tf.group(op_A, op_B)
queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_B, [op] * 4)
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much. I have two follow-up questions. 1. What is the difference between `op = tf.group(op_A, op_B)   queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_B, [op] * 4)` and `queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_B, [op_A, op_B] * 4)`?  2. Because op_A and op_B involve two different queues, which queue should I use as the first argument of QueueRunner? queue_A or queue_B? Thanks!

Comment: In the first snippet (`[op] * 4`), `queue_runner` will create four threads that each call `sess.run(op)`, which runs the two ops together. In the second snippet, (`[op_A, op_B] * 4`), `queue_runner` will create eight threads that either call `sess.run(op_A)` or `sess.run(op_B)`, hence running the two ops separately and dequeuing separate elements for `op_A` and `op_B`.

Comment: The `queue` argument to `QueueRunner()` is not particularly significant, but it does control how a clean shutdown is performed (e.g. if you use a `tf.train.Coordinator`). You can pass either queue as the argument, but you should also pass a `close_op=tf.group(queue_A.close(), queue_B.close())` so that both queues are closed on shutdown.

Comment: Could you please explain what does this mean "You can pass either queue as the argument, but you should also pass a `close_op=tf.group(queue_A.close(), queue_B.close())`"? Pass `close_op` to the `QueueRunner()`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't explain why your code doesn't work, but it looks like *op_A* doesn't execute because it's not depend on *queue_B*, and I suggest you to use control flow op (for example [tf.group](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#group)) for achieving what your want.

```
op = tf.group(op_A, op_B)
queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_B,
                                    [op] * 4)
```