# Tensorflow sum tensor from before and after queue

Tags: tensorflow

What would happen with this:
[image]

What I want is that (out1, out2) to the summation is from the same input.
However, as Queue2 is continuously doing enqueue, is the content of out1 also changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make this work is to enqueue `out1` into `queue2` alongside the result of `op1(out1)`. Here's a rough example of how it would look, using two [`tf.FIFOQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#FIFOQueue) queues (assuming that all :

```
queue1 = tf.FIFOQueue(dtypes=[tf.float32])

# First component will store `out1`; second will store `op1(out1)`.
queue2 = tf.FIFOQueue(dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.float32])

# Define an op that enqueues to `queue1`.
enqueue1_op = ...

out1 = queue1.dequeue()
processed_out1 = op1(out1)

# Define an op that enqueues `out1` and `processed_out1` together to `queue2`.
enqueue2_op = queue2.enqueue([out1, processed_out1])

dequeued_out1, dequeued_processed_out1 = queue2.dequeue()
result = tf.add(dequeued_out1, dequeued_processed_out1)
```

Comment: I tried to put processed_out1 and out1 in two different queues with their own queue runners (single threaded). I expect it should also work because the queue i use is a fifoqueue. But the output seems to be summing out1 and processed_out1 from different inputs. Despite that it is better putting them in a tuple in the queue, what is going wrong with two queues?

Comment: I'm not sure (without seeing your code) but my guess is that the two queue runners are dequeuing different elements from `queue1`, because they're running different steps. See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39126724/3574081) for an explanation of how things can go wrong in that case.

Comment: If enqueue op of each queue runner should be considered as an individual sess.run call. I think I figure out what's happening now. Thanks a lot for your help!